# Determine whether the sequence converges or diverges. If it converges, find the limit.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Determine whether the sequence converges or diverges. If it converges, find the limit.

$$\left\{\frac{\ln4n}{\ln12n}\right\}$$

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\ln4n}{\ln12n} =$ ?

I am having trouble with this problem, any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 4):

the limit is $1$. Write:$$\dfrac{\ln (4n)}{\ln (12n)} = \dfrac{\ln 4 + \ln n}{\ln 12 + \ln n} = \dfrac{1+\dfrac{\ln 4}{\ln n}}{1+\dfrac{\ln 12}{\ln n}}$$.

If instead you want to change the question to: $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{\ln(4+n)}{\ln(12+n)} = \text{ ?? }$, then you would apply the same trick as above:

$\ln(4+n) = \ln n + \ln\left(1+\dfrac{4}{n}\right)$, and divide top and bottom by $\ln n$ again as above.

Comment: I have a quick questions about why you separated it from ln(4n) to ln4 + lnn and on the bottom as well? and what would happen if you started out with ln(4+n) instead of ln(4n) on the top?

Comment: I edited it, check it out and ask if you have further question about it.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to
BRICS-Fan
but a little simpler:

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{\ln4n}{\ln12n}
&=\dfrac{\ln n+\ln 4}{\ln n+\ln 12}\\
&=\dfrac{\ln n+\ln 12-\ln 12+\ln 4}{\ln n+\ln 12}\\
&=1+\dfrac{-\ln 12+\ln 4}{\ln n+\ln 12}\\
&=1+\dfrac{-\ln 3}{\ln n+\ln 12}\\
&\to 1\\
\end{array}
$

since
$\frac{-\ln 3}{\ln n+\ln 12}
\to 0
$.